# Perl compatible regular expressions with character classes not recognized in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell, pcre

I'm looking to use perl compatible regular expressions in Haskell,  specifically the short-hand character classes `\w` and `\s`, etc.

I understand these are not available in the standard posix module:

```
import Text.Regex.Posix

"this is a string" =~ "\S+"

<interactive>:3:25: error:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character 'S'
```

However, I expected the pcre package to handle this, but see the same result:

```
import Text.Regex.PCRE

"this is a string" =~ "\S+"

<interactive>:2:25: error:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character 'S'
```

In python, it would work like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\S+', "this is a string")
['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']
```

How can I use these regex character classes in Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with regexes or with Haskell vs. Python. Note that you wouldn't write `re.findall("\S+", "this is a string")` either<sup>†</sup>. You need *raw string literals* to use backslashes like this. Haskell doesn't have raw string literals built in, but it does have quasi quoters that allows you to [emulate them](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq).

```
Prelude> :set -XQuasiQuotes 
Prelude> :m +Text.RawString.QQ Text.Regex.PCRE
Prelude Text.RawString.QQ Text.Regex.PCRE> "this is a string" =~ [r|\S+|] :: String
"this"
```

Alternatively, just double-escape the backslashes: `"this is a string" =~ "\\S+"`

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually it turns out that the single-backslash version works in Python even with simple quotes, but this seems to be a fallback rule. Better don'y rely on this.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

With Posix you can use:

```
\w ...  [\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}]
\W ...  [\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}]
\s ...  [[:space:]]
\S ...  [^[:space:]]
\d ...  [[:digit:]]
\D ...  [^[:digit:]]
```

With PCRE Package you can use:

```
\w ...  [\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nl}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]
\W ...  [^\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nl}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]
\s ...  [\p{Z}\t\n\cK\f\r\x85]
\S ...  [^\p{Z}\t\n\cK\f\r\x85]
\d ...  \p{Nd}
\D ...  \P{Nd}
```